# Javascript validation bug

Tags: javascript

Please imagine this part of a web form. Two checkboxes (with the same name="myCheckbox") and two text inputs. If the first checkbox is checked, the first text input must not be empty. If the second checkbox is checked, the second text input must not be empty. To validate this I use the script below:

```
// huge validation code above   

}else if (!document.myForm.myCheckbox[0].checked && !document.myForm.myCheckbox[1].checked){ 
    jAlert ('Please select one of the two checkboxes!',function(){$(myForm.myCheckbox).focus();}); 
    return false;   

}else if (myForm.myCheckbox[0].checked && myForm.myFirstTextInput.value=="") {
    jAlert ('You have selected the first checkbox. Please make sure that the first text input is not empty!',function(){$(myForm.myFirstTextInput).focus();});
    return false;

}else if (myForm.myCheckbox[1].checked && myForm.mySecondTextInput.value=="") {
    jAlert ('You have selected the second checkbox. Please make sure that the second text input is not empty!',function(){$(myForm.mySecondTextInput).focus();});
    return false;

// huge validation code below
```

Everything works just fine. But now, I also want to check if in the first text input the user has entered at least 10 digits. I update my validation code, please see below:

```
// huge validation code above   

}else if (!document.myForm.myCheckbox[0].checked && !document.myForm.myCheckbox[1].checked){ 
    jAlert ('Please select one of the two checkboxes!',function(){$(myForm.myCheckbox).focus();}); 
    return false;   

}else if (myForm.myCheckbox[0].checked && myForm.myFirstTextInput.value=="") {
    jAlert ('You have selected the first checkbox. Please make sure that the    first text input is not empty!',function(){$(myForm.myFirstTextInput).focus();});
    return false;

}else if (myForm.myCheckbox[0].checked && myForm.myFirstTextInput.value!=="")
var x = document.getElementById("myFirstTextInput");
var y = x.value;
var totalNrOfDigits = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++){
if(/\d/.test(y[i])){
totalNrOfDigits++;
}
}
if(totalNrOfDigits < 10) {
jAlert ('Please make sure that the first text input contains at least 10 digits!',function(){$(myForm.myFirstTextInput).focus();});
return false;   


}else if (myForm.myCheckbox[1].checked && myForm.mySecondTextInput.value=="") {
    jAlert ('You have selected the second checkbox. Please make sure that the second text input is not empty!',function(){$(myForm.mySecondTextInput).focus();});
    return false;

// huge validation code below
```

My problem: after I add the check for at least 10 digits, if the users clicks the SECOND check box, then "mySecondTextInput" is no longer validated and the form is submitted. I really don't get it why and already wasted most of may day...

Sorry because I have not added the whole code: It's really huge, it's a pretty complex web form.

Answer (score 0):

In the second code example, you forgot the opening curly bracket on line 11, so only the first statement following the `else if` condition will be evaluated.

```
}else if (myForm.myCheckbox[0].checked && myForm.myFirstTextInput.value!=="")
                                                                              ^
                                                                              |
```

Comment: Edited my code, intially added an extra }. Sorry, that's not it, but thank you.